# Calculate and create species richness and Estimated value and Residuals value map from polygons

Tags: r, arcgis

I want to Calculate and create Maps for species richness and Estimated value and Residuals value from polygons by using ArcGIS or SAM Software as I attached example for map as I want. I have shapefile for my study area and shapefile for species. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJT0Y.jpg).